# How to add new tabs in post.php

Tags: plugins, posts

i would like to add meta boxes inside the new tab.
I have attached an image where I want to add a tab.
Kindly help me out if you have any solution,

[image]

I have checked this solution but it does not use full
[How to add a new tab to page editor](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/122922/how-to-add-a-new-tab-to-page-editor)

Comment: Related question in SO, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64426030/is-there-a-way-to-add-new-tab-in-wordpress-gutenberg-editor